# How do I get the width attribute via class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the attribute `width` with in class

```
<div class="one" >
  <img src="1.png" class="two">
<div>
    <div class="three" >
   <img src="2.png" class="two">
<div>
```

I want get second class attribute `1.png` using class `one` and class `two`.

Comment: example is not class attribute it is data can you clarify this

Comment: i have updated question. Nuw you can understand

Comment: still not clear `i want get second class attribute "1.png" using class one and class two.` can you tell what the expected output based on what?

Comment: @Osiz4 If any of the answers were helpful please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a global object named `document`. You don't need JQuery to use its `querySelector` function.

That object has a method called `querySelector`. If you call `querySelector` as a function, and pass in the classes you want to find, prepended by a `.` period, it will find those elements for you.

After you have selected those elements, you can get the attribute by calling the `getAttribute` method with the parameter of the attribute you need.

`document.querySelector('.one .two').getAttribute('src')`

[More information on the queryselector can be found **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

try with jquery like this 
for your edited questions

```
var getAttribute = $(".one .two").attr("src");
 alert(getAttribute);
```

see the demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="one" >
   <img src="1.png" class="two">
 </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var s = $(".one .two").attr("src");
 alert(s);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) passing a selector as a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas, in this case `.one > .two` which means:

- select a an element with class `.two` child of an element with class `.one`.

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('.one > .two').getAttribute('src');
console.log(elm);
```

```html
<div class="one" >
  <img src="1.png" class="two">
<div>
    <div class="three" >
   <img src="2.png" class="two">
<div>
```